# Need help calculating checksum (crc-16) from a string of data

Tags: crc16

I need help calculating the checksum (crc-16:X16+X15+X2+1) for BYTE6 and BYTE7 of this data string. I have read some examples but I have no idea how and where to start. What does the X16, X15 etc means? What should I put in BYTE6 and BYTE7?

Byte0: 0x55

Byte1: 0x80

Byte2: 0x06

Byte3: 0x02

Byte4: 0x00

Byte5: 0x00

Byte6: MSB of the checksum word (CRC-16)

Byte7: LSB of the checksum word (CRC-16)

Comment: This is an IBM CRC polynom as stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks. Those X16, etc... are X to the power of 16, etc... In which language do you want that done?

Comment: For now I just want to understand the basic concept of it, however i would use the C language

Comment: a quick lookup on this site could have lead to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638939/crc-16-ibm-reverse-lookup-in-c

Answer (score 0):

The CRC polynomial (x<sup>16</sup>+x<sup>15</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>+1) is necessary but not sufficient to define the CRC. You can see [this list of 16-bit CRCs](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm), in which you can find seven different CRC's that use that particular polynomial (`poly=0x8005`).

Once you have the full description, you can use [my `crcany` code](https://github.com/madler/crcany) to generate C code to compute the CRC.

Comment: I cloned your project and successfully built it and test, but having trouble figuring out how to use it. I want to obtain a crc16/ibm-sdlc for a few hex bytes of data. Can you show me the process for doing this please?

Comment: `% echo -n 123456789 | ./crcany -sdlc`, result: `CRC-16/IBM-SDLC: 0x906e`. Make a file with your binary data. Then: `./crcany -sdlc datafile`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. That helps a lot. For the data file, does it presume an ascii hex representation? ie "080a18ff40" or would the txt file be "0x08 0x0a 0x18 0xff 0x40"?

Comment: No. Those actual bytes. The file would be five bytes in length.